# Error de Unity con System.Security.Cryptography.Xml

Tags: c#, xml, unity, unity2d

estoy haciendo un proyecto 2d con Unity y para guardar el progreso que hace en los diferentes niveles y para ello utilizo archivos xml,los archivos el pprograma me lo crea, pero el problema es que lo quiero encriptar y desencriptar, pero cuando pongo en using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml, Unity me da el siguiente error,
**Assets\xml.cs(6,36): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Xml' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security.Cryptography' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**, para intentar solucionarlo he copiado la dll de Cryptography.Xml en la carpeta, he generado dos archivos que recomendaban en otra pregunta, un archivo era mcs.rsp con el siguiente contenido: **-r:System.Security.dll;** y el siguiente archivo, csc.rsp con el siguiente contenido:

````
# The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
# See the LICENSE file in the project root for more information.

# This file contains command-line options that the C#
# command line compiler (CSC) will process as part
# of every compilation, unless the "/noconfig" option
# is specified. 

# Reference the common Framework libraries
/r:Accessibility.dll
/r:Microsoft.CSharp.dll
/r:System.Configuration.dll
/r:System.Configuration.Install.dll
/r:System.Core.dll
/r:System.Data.dll
/r:System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
/r:System.Data.Linq.dll
/r:System.Data.OracleClient.dll
/r:System.Deployment.dll
/r:System.Design.dll
/r:System.DirectoryServices.dll
/r:System.dll
/r:System.Drawing.Design.dll
/r:System.Drawing.dll
/r:System.EnterpriseServices.dll
/r:System.Management.dll
/r:System.Messaging.dll
/r:System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
/r:System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
/r:System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.dll
/r:System.Security.Cryptography.Xml
/r:System.Security.dll
/r:System.ServiceModel.dll
/r:System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
/r:System.ServiceProcess.dll
/r:System.Transactions.dll
/r:System.Web.dll
/r:System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll
/r:System.Web.Extensions.dll
/r:System.Web.Mobile.dll
/r:System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll
/r:System.Web.Services.dll
/r:System.Windows.Forms.dll
/r:System.Workflow.Activities.dll
/r:System.Workflow.ComponentModel.dll
/r:System.Workflow.Runtime.dll
/r:System.Xml.dll
/r:System.Xml.Linq.dll
/r:System.Net.Http.dll, 
pero cuando pongo los dos archivos adjuntos, me da el siguiente error: Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.5.0-dev-20359-01 (8da8ba0c)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

warning CS2023: Ignoring /noconfig option because it was specified in a response file
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\.NET' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\Foundation' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\licenses' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\this' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\file' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\to' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\you' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\under' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\the' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\MIT' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\license.' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\Licensed' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\See' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\LICENSE' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\contains' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\in' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\command-line' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\options' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\project' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\one' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\root' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\that' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\or' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\for' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\more' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\information.' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\agreements.' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\This' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\The' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\C#' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\line' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\command' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\as' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\compiler' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\common' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\part' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\Framework' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\(CSC)' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\of' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\libraries' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\will' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\every' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\compilation,' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\process' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\unless' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\option' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\is' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\specified.' could not be found.
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\sepul\New Unity Project (3)\Reference' could not be found.``` 
Muchas gracias de antemano
Y tambien, el codigo que tengo para encriptar y desencriptar es el de la siguiente pagina, gracias
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.encryptedxml.encrypt?view=net-5.0
````

Comment: Añadiste esa libreria a las referencias de tu proyecto? Explorador de soluciones/clic derecho sobre la carpeta refernces/add references

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249281/the-type-or-namespace-name-xml-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-securit entra aqui

Comment: Hola Buenas, si, le añadí la referencia al proyecto y el seguia dando error